# Como puedo sincronizar los datos con mi servidor en Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

Al darle para que sincronicen los datos de la BD con el BDLITE del android, me sale este error de convertirlo en boolean que no comprendo bien,no me vota error de codigo mas que esto, porfavor su apoyo

> E/SISTEMA: entro a sincro
> --------- beginning of crash E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-6    Process: com.example.martapp, PID: 20208
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'boolean
> com.example.martapp.dbMartellApp.isTableExists(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,
> java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
> at com.example.martapp.caNavigation.SincronizaTotal(caNavigation.java:141)
> at com.example.martapp.caNavigation$2.run(caNavigation.java:122)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919) E/GraphicExt: GraphicExtModuleLoader::CreateGraphicExtInstance false

Estas son las funciones que utilice, aca muestra en un AppCompatActivity:

```
dbMartellApp xdba ;        
public void Sincroniza(){
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(caNavigation.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Sincronizando..."); // Setting Message
                progressDialog.setTitle("STARSOFT"); // Setting Title
                progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER); // Progress Dialog Style Spinner
                progressDialog.show(); // Display Progress Dialog
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                      //  try {
                            // Thread.sleep(5000);
                            Log.e(TAG,"entro a sincro");
                            SincronizaTotal();
                            Log.e(TAG,"salio de sincro");
                    //    } catch (Exception e) {
                           // Log.e(TAG,"activo ex");
                         //   e.printStackTrace();
                       // }
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).start();
            }
            public void SincronizaTotal()
            {

            Boolean
                    resp=xdba.isTableExists(db,"tbusuarios");
            Log.e(TAG,"dentro de sincro  usu" + resp.toString());
                Boolean xrespart=xdba.ImportacionMatrizMaeCli(Global.xxcodvendedorwenco);
            Log.e(TAG,"dentro de sincro " + xrespart.toString());
            if(xrespart) {
                messagebox("Martell dice:", "IMPORTACION COMPLETA");
            }
        }
```

Y esta es la clase dbMartellApp.JAVA con extedns SQLiteOpenHelper que llama a la funcion ImporacticonMatrizMaecli, aca llama los datos del servidor y si ya tiene solo lo selecciona.

```
public boolean ImportacionMatrizMaeCli(String xcodvendedor) {
    Boolean res;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    JSONParser json = new JSONParser();
    Integer xreg;
    Boolean xresp;
    //primero limpio la tabla para evitar la duplicidad

Boolean resp4 = isTableExists(db, "tempmaecli");
if (resp4) {
    String strSQL23 = "DELETE FROM tempmaecli;";
    db.execSQL(strSQL23);
}



String url = XXURL + "?xtipo=8&xparamint1=0&xparamint2=0&xparamint3=0&xparamstring1=" + Global.xxcodvendedorwenco + "&xparamstring2=0&xparamstring3=0";
//Log.e(TAG,url);
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONParser().Reading(url);
xreg = jsonArray.length();
if (xreg > 0) {
    res=true;
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String xccodcli = jsonObject.getString("ccodcli");
            String xcnomcli = jsonObject.getString("cnomcli");
            // xcnomcli=xcnomcli.replaceAll("\\s+","");
            xcnomcli=xcnomcli.replaceAll("\\s+$","");

            String xcnumruc = jsonObject.getString("cnumruc");
            String xcdircli = jsonObject.getString("cdircli");
            String xCOMENTA=jsonObject.getString("COMENTA");
            String xSUBCLA01=jsonObject.getString("SUBCLA01");
            xSUBCLA01=xSUBCLA01.replaceAll("\\s+","");
            String xSUBCLA02=jsonObject.getString("SUBCLA02");
            xSUBCLA02=xSUBCLA02.replaceAll("\\s+","");
            String xctelefo=jsonObject.getString("ctelefo");
            xctelefo=xctelefo.replaceAll("\\s+","");
            String xlimite=jsonObject.getString("lmcrmn");
            String xcvende=jsonObject.getString("cvende");

            //proceso de inercion
            //String strSQLx = "create table tbproducto(idproducto INTEGER,nombre TEXT,iduv INTEGER,uventa TEXT,codebar TEXT,foto TEXT)";
            String strSQL="insert into tempmaecli(ccodcli,cnomcli,cdircli,cnumruc,cvende,comenta ,subcla01 ,subcla02 ,ctelefo,limite) values('" + xccodcli + "','" + xcnomcli + "','" + xcdircli + "','" + xcnumruc + "','" + xcvende + "','" + xCOMENTA + "','" + xSUBCLA01 + "','" + xSUBCLA02 + "','" + xctelefo + "'," + xlimite + ")";
            Log.e(TAG,strSQL);
            xresp=ExeSQL(db,strSQL);
            if(xresp)
            {
                Log.e(TAG,strSQL);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e(TAG,"FALLA EN IMPORTACION DE CLIENTES");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} else {
    res=false;
    Log.e(TAG, "SIN REGISTROS");
}

return res;
```

}

Comment: Lo que te dice el error es que el objeto `xdba` sobre el que ejecutas el método `isTableExists` es `null`, o no lo has inicializado, o en ese momento de la ejecución no le has dado valor.

Comment: Estás creando Boolean como objeto, no boolean como valor primitivo, eso puede ser un problema.
En cuanto al error te pone: xdba no está inicializado.

Comment: Muchas gracias ya corregi el error, exactamente xdba no lo reconia como tal, ahora salen mas error pero es la continuacion del codigo, graciaaas